# Update query (Not working)

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to make a CMS, but it does not update the database when I change the values like **inkoop to 40**.

Do you see anything wrong in my sql query ?
I have tried alot of changes and even put the `` at the desc value but nothing happens.

Here is the code :

```
 <?php
    $prodid = $_GET['prodid'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $shopid1 = $_POST['productid'];
        $prodname1 = $_POST['productname'];
        $desc1 = $_POST['desc'];
        $fprice1 = $_POST['fprice'];
        $price1 = $_POST['price'];
        $inkoop1 = $_POST['inkoop'];
        $image1 = $_POST['image'];
        $qty1 = $_POST['qty'];
        $html1 = $_POST['html'];
        $author1 = $_SESSION['name'];


        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET shopid='$shopid1', name='$prodname1', qty='$qty1', price='$price1', `desc`='$desc1', fprice='$fprice1', inkoop='$inkoop1', image='$image1', author='$author1', html='$html1' WHERE id=$prodid");

            Header("Location: products.php");

    } else {

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: 1) You should **not** use `mysql_*()` functions as they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` instead 2) Add some debug output with `mysqli_error()`. Those errors are some times quite self explanatory.

Comment: Take the time to learn how to use pdo: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
It's really worth it

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to a database? => Have you called `mysql_connect` before trying to execute `mysql_query`?

Comment: if you taken a image as a file then you can't access file using $_POST for that you have to use $_FILES.

Comment: Try putting the last field `id` you are querying in single quotes
So `... WHERE \`id\`='$prodid'...`
If that doesn't work, try the query directly into an SQL client so you can see the error output.